# Can you take the conjugate of both sides of a complex equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

For example $a+bi = x$,
Can $a-bi=\bar x$

Where $i$ is the square root of $-1$?

Comment: Yes, certainly you can do so.

Comment: @yoyostein Can you prove it perhaps?

Comment: If $f$ is a function and $a=b$, then $f(a) = f(b)$ regardless of what the function $f$ is. In this case, $f(z) = \overline{z}$.

Comment: What does "complex *equation*" in the title refer to? If you literally mean $x=a+bi$ *with* $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\bar x = a - bi$ is indeed the definition of the complex conjugate. Otherwise if $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ then $\bar x = \bar a - \bar b i$. Or, if you meant something entirely else, then you should phrase your question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, certainly you can do so.

If $z=a+bi$, then $\bar{z}=a-bi$ by definition of complex conjugate.

Comment: Thank you I guess I just needed to think about it more. Will be marking this as the solution after the time limit expires.